# Best way to make text look fading away

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I am creating an image effect where the text at the bottom of a paragraph fades away**
This is the effect I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
I have some working HTML & CSS which achieves this look but I am looking to see if there is a better way to achieve this effect? I've often found that there are HTML tricks to do what I want that I dont know of.

I'm open to using JQuery if it has the ability to do this effect but a native HTML CSS effect would be best. Plus is my solution cross browser?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        body { 
            background-color: blue;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0 auto;
        }

        #mainContent {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0 auto;
        }

        .textContainer {
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        .recipeContentOverlay {
            z-index: 5;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 80px;
        }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mainContent">
        <div class="textContainer">
            <h2 class="recipeText">Ingredients:</h2>
            <p class="recipeText">Have you ever had broccoli rabe (pronounced "rahb" or "rah-bee" depending on where you are from)? I have sort of a love hate relationship with it. It looks like broccoli, but it doesn't taste like it. Broccoli rabe can sometimes be so bitter, even with blanching, there's no amount of vinegar or bacon that can save it. But bitterness heightens flavors</p>

            <img class="recipeContentOverlay" src="images/overlay.png" width="100%" height="200px"/>
            <!-- The idea is to get the above image to sit slightly over the top of the above "p" element so that some of the text 
                 fades away. Is there a better way to acheive the same look/effect? -->
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Text fading away becomes a bit hard to read, are you sure you want it?

Comment: The striking blue background isn't very good for text readability either ;)

Comment: Would adding a gradient effect to you text having it fade to the background color be acceptable? You would still be able to select the text however.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, lol the blue background is an example, its really white so it blends in well. I think I'll keep the fade away but because it's meant to give a blurb example of the recipe text, I want to force the user to click through to see the whole text/recipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Basically we use CSS gradients and opacity to set the color.

http://jsfiddle.net/V45LW/

You can use a site [like this one](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to help with getting the css written. Basically what you do is absolutely position a div at end of paragraph of fixed height. We apply a gradient opacity change to it.

```
div.fade {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%, rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(125,185,232,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(30,87,153,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,185,232,0) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#1e5799',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), a legal way to embed [almost] any font into a webpage through Javascript. You'd just include the Cufon API as usual, and your Javascript code would look like this:

```
Cufon.replace('.paragraph', { color: '-linear-gradient(black, blue)' });
```

What this does is select the element with class "paragraph" (CSS selectors can only be used if you have a library that supports it on your webpage too, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and sets its color to a linear gradient. In this case I made it go from black to blue so that by the end it blends in with your background color (according to the image you showed us, that is).

I'll get a live demo up soon.

Fair warning though, text fading into the background is not exactly user friendly. It's up to you whether you'd like to continue using it. I do admit it's a nice effect, but only when it's still perfectly legible.

Comment: Also, just highlighting the text will make it visible again.

Comment: @Kolink: I don't think that would be a problem, seeing as Jake M is going to have users click a button to see the entire recipe anyways.