# How do you fade horizontal text into a vertical gradient?

Tags: css

the text fade should appear with solid text on the left and faded text on the right. in this example i made how would you fade jupiter to look like earth and mars using only css?

```
.hello-jupiter {
    display:inline-block;
    background: rgba(215, 215, 215, 1);
    color:white;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 15px -10px rgba(50, 50, 50, .5), inset 0px -10px 25px -10px rgba(50, 50, 50, .75);
}
```

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w92xv/1/) <-- actually uses box-shaodw and not a gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer. I just floated a div to the right faded it from 0 to 100% opacity.

```
.hello-jupiter {
    display:inline-block;
    background: rgba(215, 215, 215, 1);
    color:white;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 15px -10px rgba(50, 50, 50, .5), inset 0px -10px 25px -10px rgba(50, 50, 50, .75);
    position:relative;
}

.fader {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    display:block;
    width:75px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 75%)
}
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/w92xv/45/

Answer (score 0):

I find this website is handy for CSS...

http://www.css3maker.com/css-gradient.html

CSS generated from the [css3maker](http://www.css3maker.com/) website:

```
.hello-jupiter {
    display:inline-block;
    background: rgba(215, 215, 215, 1);
    color:white;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 0%, 37% 0%, from(#FFFFFF), to(#000000))
}
```

This will only work in Chrome and Safari versions 4.0+

Comment: this just generates a gradient. the question is how you fade text into a gradient

Comment: okay, been up all night and misread the full request. try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942953/best-way-to-make-text-look-fading-away

Comment: limited to webkit but there's also this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/